# Hearing the difference between 他 vs 大

Tags: mandarin, listening

When listening to normal conversation or fast spoken Mandarin chinese, can native speakers still hear the aspiration in 他 vs 大, particularly if relying only on sound or what is heard?

As an English speaker, I have to say that I find that I hear little difference.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148659/discussion-on-question-by-user55570-hearing-the-difference-between--vs-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

他 starts with a [tʰ] (pinyin "t") which is aspirated. It is like most of the "t"s in English, for example: top or tap

大 starts with a [t]  (pinyin "d") which is non-aspirated. It is like the "t"s in "start" or "stop"

The problem is in the pinyin. The "d" in pinyin is not a true voiced consonant. it is just a non-aspirated t. It is not the same as an English d.

As a native Chinese speaker, I only realized this when I started to learn French where most "t"s are non-aspirated.

Check this two links for more information about t and aspiration:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_and_alveolar_plosives

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant

Comment: The confusion is to the English speakers. I doubt there is any Chinese native who couldn't distinguish the two sounds.

Comment: @r13 agree. [t] vs [tʰ] is just for English speakers. For Chinese speakers, some have problem to distinguish [d] vs [t].(for example: Hindi has [t] vs [tʰ], and some India people with accent will say "time" as [t]ime, to some Chinese, they would think the India accent says [d]ime, but it is not, it is just a non-aspirated [t]. Hindi even has [dʰ] which I can't even imagine how to pronounce lol ) It is always hard to get used to something that rarely show or does not exist in one's native tongue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the video files to hear the differences between the pronunciations of 大 and 他, and their starting sound - ㄉ(d) and ㄊ(t) respectively.

[image] [發音](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKmwhmI0mBE)

● 大 [dà/**ㄉ**ㄚˋ] https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%A4%A7

● 他 [tā/**ㄊ**ㄚˉ] https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BB%96

[Other Examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTjeYe5iKW4) - pay attention to 0:20 (ㄉ); 0:34 (ㄊ)

**ADD: 拼音 注音 对照**

[image]
[拼音-注音 对照](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1hh411Q7hR/)